# R: Aggregate (sum) based on a single column but keep all other columns?

Tags: r, aggregate

I am working with a dataset with many columns. I want to know if there is a way to aggregate rows based on a single column but keep all the other columns.

I am aware of doing it this way:

```
aggregate(data$col.to.be.summed, by=list(data$col1, data$col2, data$col3), FUN=sum)
```

However, I have over 60 columns so is there a way to do this without the list function? i.e. just tell R to include all the other columns?

The data, for arguments sake, are equivalent to this where all other columns contain the same information for each sampling event over a number of rows (but with many more columns):

```
> col.to.be.summed   col1   col2   col3
>                0      1     XX      A
>                2      1     XX      A
>                0      1     XX      A
>                0      2     XX      B
>                0      3     YY      A
>                4      3     YY      A
```

I want to end up with this:

```
> col.to.be.summed   col1   col2   col3
>                2      1      XX      A
>                0      2      XX      B
>                4      3      YY      A
```

I imagine there is a straightforward command to tell R to retain all other columns without listing them manually, but I can't find it after hours of searching :/

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: It's frustrating when you could have just copied and pasted all those variable names in 5 minutes but you spent 2 hours looking for the programatic solution. At least there's learning!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reformulate` to create a formula dynamically which can be used in `aggregate`.

```
aggregate(reformulate(names(data)[-1], 'col.to.be.summed'), data, sum)
```

where

```
reformulate(names(data)[-1], 'col.to.be.summed') #returns

#col.to.be.summed ~ col1 + col2 + col3
```

You can replace `names(data)[-1]` with the columns that you want to group by. This works too `names(data)[2:4]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr) # Version > 1.0.0
data %>% 
   group_by(across(-col.to.be.summed)) %>%
   summarise(x = sum(col.to.be.summed, na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   col1, col2 [3]
   col1 col2  col3      x
  <int> <chr> <chr> <int>
1     1 XX    A         2
2     2 XX    B         0
3     3 YY    A         4
```